# How to 1st table distinct and sum and join 2nd table, which if not match between T1 and T2 then add new row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to join 1st table distinct and sum and join 2nd table, which  if not match between T1  and T2 then add new row

[image]

[image]

Result i need

- Period in result table is Getdate()

[image]

```
Select distinct(y.Emp_ID),x.MealAllowance_OT from [dbo].[SPCM_TX_MonthlyAllowance] y left join 
  (Select x.Emp_Id,x.MealAllowance_OT from [dbo].[SPCM_Cal_OTLog] x
   group by x.Emp_Id,x.MealAllowance_OT) x
on x.Emp_Id = y.Emp_ID
order by x.MealAllowance_OT desc
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Explain the logic for the `period` and how the other values change as well.

Comment: Add the query you've attempted to your question.

Comment: Yes, i will take your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a subquery on T2 to get sums by group.  Then you outer join with T1 to include non-matching rows.
I guessed at the math and the defaults.  Like why is Pay/MealAllowance presumed to be 400 when there isn't an entry in T1.

```
declare @T1 table (Emp_Id int, TRA varchar(3), Pay int)
declare @T2 table (Emp_Id int, DayTy varchar(3), MealAllowance int)

insert into @T1
values (1,'DL',400),(2,'IDL',400),(5,'IDL',400)

insert into @T2
values (1,'DL',18),(2,'IDL',136),(2,'IDL',136),(4,'IDL',136)

select isnull(T1.Emp_Id,T2.Emp_Id) Emp_Id,isnull(T1.TRA,T2.DayTy) DayTY
   ,isnull(Pay,400) MealAllowance_Mont, isnull(MealAllowance,0) MealAllowance
   ,isnull(Pay,400) + isnull(MealAllowance,0) Tot, getdate() period
from @T1 T1
full outer join
(
   select Emp_Id, DayTy,sum(MealAllowance) MealAllowance
   from @T2
   group by Emp_Id, DayTy
) T2
   on T1.Emp_Id = T2.Emp_Id
   and T1.TRA = T2.DayTy
```

Comment: Oh I’m terribly sorrysomething wrong on my example table but your script Perfect. I can adapt it  to fit my requirement